# Intel pin: How does RTN_InsertCall works?

Tags: c++, profiling, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

The `RTN_InsertCall` in intel Pin has its definition as

```
VOID LEVEL_PINCLIENT::RTN_InsertCall(
    RTN     rtn,
    IPOINT  action,
    AFUNPTR funptr,
    ... 
)
```

It can call the function `funptr` with the arguments provided in `...` (before or after calling the function represented by rtn).

Example:

```
void func1(int a) {
    printf("Argument : %d", a);
}

...

RTN_InsertCall(funcRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)func1, 
               IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0, 
               IARG_END);
```

```
void func2(int a, int b) {
    printf("Argument : %d %d", a, b);
}

...

RTN_InsertCall(funcRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)func1, 
               IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0, 
               IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 1, 
               IARG_END);
```

How does this function work? How to call a non-variadic function(and the number of arguments may vary) inside a variadic function?

Btw, the `RTN_InsertCall` is used to insert an additional function(func1 / func2) before actually execute the target function(funcRtn). What can we do if we don't know the number of arguments of `funcRtn`? How to convert the func1 / func2 into variadic functions?